# How to address classes within an ng-bootstrap component?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I want to add a css style to a NgbProgressbar and I'm having trouble doing so.  Specifically, I want to give a custom color to the progress bar.  Using the "Contextual progress bars" demo at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar, the code for the src/progressbar-basic.ts file is:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-progressbar-basic',
    templateUrl: 'src/progressbar-basic.html',
    styles: [`
        ngb-progressbar {
            margin-top: 5rem;
        }
    `]
})
export class NgbdProgressbarBasic {
}
```

Inspecting the components in a browser, the background-color style for the progress bar is controlled by .bg-success and .progress-bar.  Adding

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color:#ff9900;
}
```

to a css file attached to the index.html file makes the desired change, but I'm trying to add it only here, rather than globally.

Adding it as done for the ngb-progressbar margin-top style above doesn't seem to work, though I don't see any effect of the margin-top style either. I've turned off the type="success" type statements in progressbar-basic.html to keep them from conflicting.

How can one modify the progressbar-basic.ts code above to attach a style to the progress-bar inside the NgbProgressbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has more to do with how styles encapsulation work in Angular rather than something specific to [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io), but the short answer is that in the default style encapsulation (from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html):

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's
>   own template

Since [ngb-progressbar](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar) is *not* part of the component HTML (it is a different component altogether) you have to force styles to propagate down the components structure:

> Use the /deep/ selector to force a style down through the child
>   component tree into all the child component views. The /deep/ selector
>   works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the
>   view children and content children of the component

Translating this to your particular problem would mean that you should write:

```
  styles: [`
    /deep/ div.bg-success {
      background-color: #ff9900!important; 
    }
  `]
```

Here is a live example in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DwBZ0Lr55onprz8bEcKI?p=preview

A word of warning: while the above works I would rather create a new *type* of a progressbar in your CSS and use it type as an argument to the ngb-progressbar `type` input. This would give you a chance to properly *name* a new concept that you are trying to express here.

Comment: I see that  /deep/ div.progress-bar also works.  I will explore Component Styles to get a better understanding of this stuff.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.